# Trouble with the Z axis in Orthographic projection

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, graphics, equation

I've been having trouble understanding why the transformation of the Z coordinate in orthographic projection is the way it is in a right-handed coordinate system.

The "function" for Z using the matrix everyone uses is:

```
f(z) = -2*z/(far-near) - (far+near)/(far-near)
```

As far as I know the way orthographic projection works is that it should map the left/right, top/bottom, near/far coordinates to 1/-1.

But if we substitute the near and far coordinates in we get:

```
f(far) = -2*far/(far-near) - (far+near)/(far-near) = (-3*far - near)/(far - near)
f(near) = -2*near/(far-near) - (far+near)/(far-near) = (-far - 3*near)/(far-near)
```

Which in most cases won't give back -1 and +1.

Basically my assumption would be that the entire function should be negated (compared to how the X and Y coordinates are computed), but instead the "translation" part stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

The `near` and `far` values are actually the distances to the corresponding depth clipping planes and are thus positive values. The coordinate frame to consider is `(e_x, e_y, e_z)` with `e_x` pointing to the right, `e_y` pointing upwards and `e_z` pointing towards the camera / eye. In this coordinate frame, the z coordinates of the depth clipping planes end up being `-near` and `-far` which make the math check out as you noticed.

Comment: Okay, what I didn't realize was that I actually had to map the negatives. I redid the Math on paper and it gave the correct results. Thanks.